# holomorphic function over the disk that is real on a closed curve must be constant

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|\leq 3\}$ and real on the boundary of the square $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid Re(z)\leq1 \text{ and } Im(z)\leq 1 \}$. Prove $f$ is constant.

How to prove? Thanks.

In general, is it true that:

$f$ holomorphic in $D(0,1)$, $f$ is real on a piece-wise smooth closed curve $\gamma$, then $f$ must be constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption implies that $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is zero on the bounding curve, and therefore vanishes on the interior by the maximum modulus principle. From this it follows that $f$ is constant.

At worst you have a technical hiccup with your particular curve being only piecewise smooth.